# "Services encapsulate business functionality" vs "Services can be composed into business processes"

Tags: wcf, architecture, soa

Recently, I was reading 2 books and I came across with the following statements

*Learning WCF from Michele Leroux:*

> Services encapsulate business functionality

*[Service orientented architecture in real world](http://www.enterprisearchitecture.ir/downloads/books/ServiceOrientedArchitectureInTheRealWorld.pdf):*

> Services can be assembled (or ―composed‖) into business processes

­

> Loosely-coupled 
>   systems result in loosely-coupled business processes, [...]. Services and their 
>   associated interfaces must remain stable, enabling them to be re-configured or re-aggregated to 
>   meet the ever-changing needs of busines

Reading SOA in real world, I understood that I was suppose to make my independent (initially useless)services abstracted from a business context, and then compose and orchestrate then to do something useful, creating the business layer and meting the business needs.

Then, reading *Learning WCF* made me to think that I should make my business layer to met a specific need and then expose it as a service(of course in a non platform specific format)

Currently, I'm making my business layer and then exposing some of it's public methods via well defined interfaces, but I liked the idea of making more independent services and compose then to make the business layer.

I would like to hear from experienced SOA developers, **what of those approaches would be ideal to get the benefits of SOA and why**?

I'm confuse about this topic. Examples and open source projects will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Thomas Erl's books, he categorises Services into 'Entity Services', which are fine-grained, business process agnostic services that relate to one Entity and are often used in compositions/orchestrations, and 'Task Services' which are course-grained, usually involve more than one entity, contain more business logic, have some knowledge of the business process and are not candidates for reuse/composition.

So a business process can either be implemented in one big Task Service, or it can be implemented by combining several Entity Services into a composition.

'Task Services' sound like Michelle Leroux's vision of a service, whereas SOA in Real World has more of an 'Entity Service' vision.

In Erl's vision of SOA, both types of services can live side by side. Entity Services are the prefered goal - these can be reused and composed more easily and increase business agility. But in some circumstances this might not be appropriate, and task services would be a better solution - peformance demands and encapsulating legacy code are two examples.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very clarifying. To make it better, confirm if  this is true: "Sales services" is a good candidate to be a task service, as it involves(products, services, shipping, commission and etc). ProductService, ServicesService, ShippingService and ComissionService would be entity services.

How I was suppose to implement it? A IProductService and ProductService class(etc) and my business rule in SalesBusiness exposed as ISalesServices?

I'm still looking for examples

Comment: Sales service could be a task service, (developed in c# or Java and exposed as a web service), or it could be a composite service implemented in BPEL/SCA engine and consuming Product, Services, Shipping and Commission entity services. Entity services would most likely be developed as web services in c# or Java. There aren't many  examples because it would be very complex - several projects and a dependency on a BPEL/SCA engine, an enterprise service bus, a discovery registry etc.

Comment: @DaviFiamenghi as well as the above, I recommend these books: SOA in Practice: 'The Art of Distributed System Design' by Nicolai M. Josuttis and 'Open Source SOA' by Jeff Davis

Answer (score 3):

To me the idea of a service is to encapsulate business related functionality. However, this is not the same as a business process. Often separate pieces of business functionality will need to be composed into larger units to represent entire business processes. For example, making a sale will require taking payment, shipping product, calculating sales commission. All of these are discrete pieces of business functionality that could be modelled as services but they would have to be composed to represent the entire business process

However, business processes tend to be relatively long running (more than the network timeout of a single request) so somehow the state of the business process needs to be maintained - this is one of the things Workflow and Biztalk can bring to the party.

Comment: Good description. Can you give us any advice for how to identify a service? Is is helpful to look across multiple business process and find their commonalities? Or is there a better approach? How do you know when a service is too granular or not granular enough?

Comment: @Richard Blewett, Talking about workflow, services should be exposed as activity libraries and each service operation an activity. Is that correct?